# Repeating / Looping a mp3 N no no times in android programming depending on user input

Tags: android, media-player

Hi Am trying to build an application wherein I want to receive a numeric ip from user and then play a particualr song that no of times(user i/p) in android.

Can someone guide me on this.

(loop, android, mp3, mediaplayer)
 android,mediaplayer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `MediaPlayer`, there is an API to set the looping parameter through `setLooping` method. However, I feel that the current API doesn't support a specific `n` number of iterations. To take a user input and loop `n` times, you could add a logic by registering a callback for  `onCompletionListener` through `setOnCompletionListener`.

In the callback implementation, you could restart the playback and continue to play the file until the number of iterations decreases to zero.